# Send object as get parameter with Axios

Tags: javascript, get, axios

The API expects the following GET request:

```
/resource?labels[team1]=corona&labels[team2]=virus
```

My issue is to generate this URL using the Axios params option.

I tried the following params structures and they both generate the wrong url:

```js
{
  labels: {
    team1: 'corona',
    team2: 'virus'
  }
}
```

```js
{
  labels: [
    team1: 'corona',
    team2: 'virus'
  ]
}
```

I at least thought it would work with the string indexed array but that generates no get params at all.

So, can anyone tell me how to generate the desired URL?

Comment: Have a look at Axios's `paramsSerializer`, a custom function to build your URL params

Comment: @JeremyThille can you give me an example for my use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the `paramsSerializer` with the same setup as in the axios readme. And I used the first params object from my post above..

```
paramsSerializer: (params) => {
  return qs.stringify(params, { arrayFormat: 'brackets' });
}
```